# For loop in shell script

Tags: shell, for-loop

I'm trying to print some record but I'm not able to aimed output

```
#!/bin/bash

a='xyx_n'
b='xzx_n'
c='xkx_n'

val=(1,2,4,5)
#a=($val)
for (( i=0;i<=3;i++ ))
do
         echo "$a|$b|$c|${val[$i]}" >> "/tmp/test1"
done

Output

xyx_n|xzx_n|xkx_n|1,2,4,5
xyx_n|xzx_n|xkx_n|
xyx_n|xzx_n|xkx_n|
xyx_n|xzx_n|xkx_n|
```

The output should be like below

```
xyx_n|xzx_n|xkx_n|1
xyx_n|xzx_n|xkx_n|2
xyx_n|xzx_n|xkx_n|4
xyx_n|xzx_n|xkx_n|5
```

Comment: Array assignment should be: `val=(1 2 4 5)` (no commas)

Answer (score 2):

Problem with your array initialization -

```
#!/bin/bash

a='xyx_n'
b='xzx_n'
c='xkx_n'

val=(1 2 4 5)
#a=($val)
for (( i=0;i<=3;i++ ))
do
         echo "$a|$b|$c|${val[$i]}" >> "/tmp/test1"
done

Output

xyx_n|xzx_n|xkx_n|1
xyx_n|xzx_n|xkx_n|2
xyx_n|xzx_n|xkx_n|4
xyx_n|xzx_n|xkx_n|5
```